# How can I capture a KeyUp event from Excel

Tags: c#, excel, vsto, addin-express

I'm working on a C# Excel project. The `Excel.Application` object only offers a `.OnKey` method for interacting with the keyboard. This effectively gives me a KeyDown event. But I need a KeyUp event. Any Ideas how to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution that actually works with Excel. I used this [GlobalMouseKeyHook](https://github.com/gmamaladze/globalmousekeyhook) library with ease!